# Where can I find good resources explaining conic sections?

Tags: conic-sections

I'm looking for something that explains them simply or something that has a lot of examples. The online course I'm taking doesn't explain them in much detail and I haven't managed to find something that explains it better. Mainly parabolas and hyperbolas. For parabolas, my course uses the formula $(x-h)^2 = 4p(y-k)$, so while I did find a useful video on KhanAcademy, on the subject, he uses a different formula and that just left me more confused.

Comment: Apostol's Calculus has a very nice section on conics.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following book could be a good reference:

> *Calculus With Analytic Geometry by R.A.Silverman*

Although it is an old one but it works yet. See the chapter $8$. You will see:

- Parabolas
- Ellipses and their equations
- More about Ellipses
- Hyperbolas and their equations

Comment: $\ddot\smile +$

Comment: @amWhy: I  have done nothing Amy up to this moment. :..(

Comment: But that's not true, Babak. You have done *a lot* at Math.SE...and you will continue to be a vital contributor ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks. I mean yesterday. :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzDsAudvBao&list=PL0G-Nd0V5ZMocqOkonFCUrazXO8I1EwwY 
This person gives a lot of examples in video.

Answer (score 0):

A good source which is a little more advanced is *Companion to Concrete Mathematics* by Melzak, first chapter.